# limit related to the Lambert function

Tags: limits, lambert-w

I am trying to evaluate the following limit 
$$
L=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{2 \operatorname{W}\left( -{{ e}^{-x-1}}\right)  \left( {{\operatorname{W}\left( -{{e}^{-x-1}}\right) }^{2}}+2 \operatorname{W}\left( -{{ e}^{-x-1}}\right) -2 x+1\right) }{{{\left( \operatorname{W}\left( -{{ e}^{-x-1}}\right) +1\right) }^{3}}}$$
where $W(z)$ is the principal branch of Lambert's function.
The numerical experiments show that it is $\sqrt{2}$ but the l'Hopital's rule does not produce anything useful.

Here is the numerical experiment computed with Maxima: $L(x) - \sqrt{2}$
[image: L-sqrt(2)]

Comment: What's "%"? Is it a typo?

Comment: I use Maxima, so that came from the Latex output.

Comment: It's undefined: For $x=0$, $W(-\exp(-x-1))$ becomes $W(-1/e)=-1$, so your numerator becomes 4, while the denominator is 0. L'Hospital can't help you here.

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis. The numerator and denominator tend to $0$ when $x\to 0^+$

Comment: Could you check the numerical experiments  ?

Comment: Claude: Whoops! I inputed Maple: f:=x->2*W(-exp(-x-1))*(W(-exp(-x-1))^2+2*W(-exp(-x-1))-2*x-1)/(W(-exp(-x-1))+1)^3; and then: eval(subs(x = 0, numer(f(x)))); 4 and eval(subs(x = 0, denom(f(x)))); 0. But the numerator has a typo at the sign of 1. With the correct sign Maple gives:evalf(limit(f(x), x = 0, right)); 1.33333333, agreeing with your result.

Comment: There is no typo. I have run the code several times.

Comment: @user48672: I meant a typo on MY code for Maple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Computing the Series**

First note that if $x=we^w$, then at $w=-1$,
$$\newcommand{\W}{\operatorname{W}}
\begin{align}
x^{(k)}
&=(w+k)e^w\\
&=(k-1)e^{-1}\tag1
\end{align}
$$
So that at $w=-1$, we have the Taylor series
$$
x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k-1}{k!}e^{-1}(w+1)^k\tag2
$$
Multiplying by $e$, adding $1$, then doubling gives
$$
\begin{align}
2(ex+1)
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{2(k-1)}{k!}(w+1)^k\\
&=(w+1)^2+\frac23(w+1)^3+\frac14(w+1)^4+\frac1{15}(w+1)^5+O(w+1)^6\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Take the positive square root; i.e. $w\gt-1$:
$$
\scriptsize\sqrt{2(ex+1)}=(w+1)+\frac13(w+1)^2+\frac5{72}(w+1)^3+\frac{11}{1080}(w+1)^4+O(w+1)^5\tag4
$$
Revert the series
$$
\scriptsize\W(x)+1=\sqrt{2(ex+1)}-\frac23(ex+1)+\frac{11\sqrt2}{36}(ex+1)^{3/2}-\frac{43}{135}(ex+1)^2+O(ex+1)^{5/2}\tag5
$$
Substitute $x\mapsto-e^{-x-1}$, then apply the series $1-e^{-x}=x-\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3+O(x)^4$:
$$
\begin{align}
&\W\left(-e^{-x-1}\right)+1\\
&\scriptsize=\sqrt{2\left(1-e^{-x}\right)}-\frac23\left(1-e^{-x}\right)+\frac{11\sqrt2}{36}\left(1-e^{-x}\right)^{3/2}-\frac{43}{135}\left(1-e^{-x}\right)^2+O\left(1-e^{-x}\right)^{5/2}\\
&=\sqrt{2x}-\frac23x+\frac{\sqrt2}{18}x^{3/2}+\frac2{135}x^2+O(x)^{5/2}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Square and cube the series
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\W\left(-e^{-x-1}\right)+1\right)^2&=2x-\frac{4\sqrt2}3x^{3/2}+\frac23x^2-\frac{2\sqrt2}{45}x^{5/2}+O(x)^3\tag7\\
\left(\W\left(-e^{-x-1}\right)+1\right)^3&=2\sqrt2\,x^{3/2}-4x^2+\frac{5\sqrt2}3x^{5/2}-\frac{88}{135}x^3+O(x)^{7/2}\tag8
\end{align}
$$
Note that $(6)$ says that $\W\left(-e^{-x-1}\right)=-1+\sqrt{2x}-\frac23x+\frac{\sqrt2}{18}x^{3/2}+\frac2{135}x^2+O(x)^{5/2}$, which combined with $(7)$ and $(8)$ gives
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{2\W\left(-e^{-x-1}\right)\frac{\left(\W\left(-e^{-x-1}\right)+1\right)^2-2x}{\left(\W\left(-e^{-x-1}\right)+1\right)^3}=\frac43-\frac{\sqrt2}3\sqrt{x}-\frac8{45}x+O(x)^{3/2}}\tag9
$$

---

**Graphing the Function**

The graph in the question spans too large a domain to see clearly what the limit is. The limit is $\frac43=1.3333333$, not $\sqrt2=1.4142136$; however, the large domain, $[0,5]$ makes it hard to see what the limit is at $0$. In the graph below, the domain is $[0,0.1]$, and the line $y=\frac43$ is plotted for reference.

I have also graphed $\frac43-\frac{\sqrt2}3\sqrt{x}-\frac8{45}x$ to compare it with the actual function, but the line thickness covers the difference for most of the graph. I made that curve red so that it would be more noticeable where the difference can be seen.

[image]

---

**L'Hôpital Approach**

Taking the derivative of $x=we^w$ gives $1=(w+1)e^ww'=(w+1)\frac xww'$, so that
$$
\W'(x)=\frac{\W(x)}{x(\W(x)+1)}\tag{10}
$$
Suppose $u=-e^{-x-1}$, then $x=-1-\log(-u)$ and
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to0^+}2\W\left(-e^{-x-1}\right)\frac{\left(\W\left(-e^{-x-1}\right)+1\right)^2-2x}{\left(\W\left(-e^{-x-1}\right)+1\right)^3}\tag{11}\\
&=\lim_{u\to-1/e}2\W(u)\frac{(\W(u)+1)^2+2+2\log(-u)}{(\W(u)+1)^3}\tag{12}\\
&=-2\lim_{u\to-1/e}\frac{2(\W(u)+1)\W'(u)+\frac2u}{3(\W(u)+1)^2\W'(u)}\tag{13}\\
&=-\frac43\lim_{u\to-1/e}\frac{\W(u)+1+\frac{\W(u)+1}{\W(u)}}{(\W(u)+1)^2}\tag{14}\\
&=-\frac43\lim_{u\to-1/e}\frac1{\W(u)}\tag{15}\\[3pt]
&=\frac43\tag{16}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(11)$: the limit we seek
$(12)$: substitute $x=-1-\log(-u)$
$(13)$: pull $-2$ outside and apply L'Hôpital
$(14)$: pull $\frac23$ outside and divide numerator and denominator by $\W'(u)$
$(15)$: divide numerator and denominator by $(\W(u)+1)^2$
$(16)$: $\W(-1/e)=-1$

Comment: Do you treat x as a composite function? I haven't thought about this.

Comment: Yes. At the beginning, I look at $x$ as a function of $w\approx-1$; i.e. $x=we^w$. Then in $(5)$, we use series reversion to get $w$ as a function of $x\ge-e^{-1}$.

Comment: Now, understand. I managed to derive it algorithmically as well.

Answer (score 2):

L'Hopital's rule works.

Note that 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} W(-\mathrm{e}^{-x-1}) = -1 \tag{1}$$ 
and
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}W(-\mathrm{e}^{-x-1}) = -\frac{W(-\mathrm{e}^{-x-1})}{W(-\mathrm{e}^{-x-1}) + 1}, 
\quad x > 0 \tag{2}$$
where we have used $W'(y) = \frac{W(y)}{y(1+W(y))}$ and the chain rule.
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Let
\begin{align}
f(x) &= W(-\mathrm{e}^{-x-1})^2 + 2W(-\mathrm{e}^{-x-1}) - 2x + 1, \\
g(x) &= (W(-\mathrm{e}^{-x-1}) + 1)^3.
\end{align}
We have (noting (2))
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= -2 W(-\mathrm{e}^{-x-1}) - 2, \quad x > 0\\
g'(x) &= -3 (W(-\mathrm{e}^{-x-1}) + 1)W(-\mathrm{e}^{-x-1}), \quad x > 0.
\end{align}

Clearly, $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} g(x) = 0$.
Also, we have (noting (1))
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{f'}{g'} = \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{2}{3 W(-\mathrm{e}^{-x-1}) } = -\frac{2}{3}.$$
By L'Hopital's rule, we have $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{f}{g} = - \frac{2}{3}$.
Thus, we have (noting (1))
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} L &= 2 \cdot \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} W(-\mathrm{e}^{-x-1}) \cdot \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{f}{g}\\
 &= \frac{4}{3}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Compose Taylor expansion starting with
$$e^{-x-1}=\frac{1}{e}-\frac{x}{e}+\frac{x^2}{2 e}-\frac{x^3}{6 e}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$W\left(-e^{-x-1}\right)=-1+\sqrt{2}\, x^{1/2}-\frac{2 x}{3}+\frac{x^{3/2}}{9 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{2 x^2}{135}-\frac{17 x^{5/2}}{48 \sqrt{2}}+O\left(x^{3}\right)$$
Then, the expression becomes
$$\frac{4}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{2} }{3}x^{1/2}-\frac{8 }{45}x+\frac{27 }{40
   \sqrt{2}}x^{3/2}+O\left(x^2\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Moreover, this gives you a shortcut method for the evaluation of the expression. For checking, let $\color{red}{x=10^{-k}}$ and compute
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 1.181577816 & 1.165840097 \\
 2 & 1.284892401 & 1.284390451 \\
 3 & 1.318263529 & 1.318247622 \\
 4 & 1.328601988 & 1.328601484 \\
 5 & 1.331840859 & 1.331840843 \\
 6 & 1.332861752 & 1.332861751 \\
 7 & 1.333184244 & 1.333184244 \\
 8 & 1.333286191 & 1.333286191 \\
 9 & 1.333318426 & 1.333318426 \\
 10 & 1.333328619 & 1.333328619
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit** *(just for your curiosity)*

Sooner or later, you will learn that for function approximations, Padé approximants are much better than Taylor series (even if the look similar). A simple one for your function is
$$\frac{\frac{4}{3}-\frac{2179 \sqrt{2} }{2457}\sqrt{x}+\frac{11798
   }{36855}x}{1-\frac{340 \sqrt{2} }{819}\sqrt{x}+\frac{815}{4914}x }$$ For $k=1$ this would give $1.165842516$ (!!).

Comment: I wanted to evaluate an asymptotic integral where $(W(-exp(x))+1)$ was in the denominator. This is why I was looking for a fractional Taylor expansion around the branch point.

Answer (score 0):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}$

\begin{align} 
L
&=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}
\frac{2 \W(-e^{-x-1})
\left(\W(-e^{-x-1})^2+2 \W(-e^{-x-1}) -2 x+1\right)}
{(\W(-e^{-x-1}) +1)^3}
\tag{1}\label{1}
\\
&=
2
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\W(-e^{-x-1})
\cdot
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}
\frac{(\W(-e^{-x-1})+1)^2-2 x}
{(\W(-e^{-x-1}) +1)^3}
\tag{2}\label{2}
=-2\cdot L_1
,\\
L_1&=
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}
\frac{(\W(-e^{-x-1})+1)^2-2 x}
{(\W(-e^{-x-1}) +1)^3}
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

Let

\begin{align} 
y&=\W(-e^{-x-1})+1
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
x&=-(y+\ln(1-y))
\tag{5}\label{5}
,
\end{align}

$y\rightarrow 0^+$ when $x\rightarrow 0^+$,
so

\begin{align} 
L_1&=
\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+}
\frac{y^2+2 (y+\ln(1-y))}
{y^3}
\tag{6}\label{6}
\end{align}

Now we can apply the L'Hopital's rule just once:

\begin{align} 
L_1&=
\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+}
\frac{2y+2-\frac2{1-y}}
{3y^2}
\tag{7}\label{7}
\\
&=
\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+}
\frac23\cdot\frac1{y-1}
=-\frac23
\tag{8}\label{8}
,
\end{align}

hence
\begin{align} 
L&=-2\cdot L_1
=\frac43
\tag{9}\label{9}
.
\end{align}

$\endgroup$